# Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined with bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue trying to load my application. I am new to React and cannot figure out what the problem is. Below are two console errors I am getting. Can someone lend a hand? I am happy to add code to this post but I am not sure what file you would need to see. I have tried going through many SO posts but a am referencing ReactDOM correctly (case wise) in my code from what the posts say. Thanks for the help!

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)


Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:6797), <anonymous>:85:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:6797)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:1151), <anonymous>:21:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1151)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:47), <anonymous>:11:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:47)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:40
```

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing your setup it's difficult, but the app is either not importing the `react-dom` module, or it's not installed at all.

Are you using a boilerplate?

Check your `package.json`.

Is there an entry similar to `"react-dom": "^15.5.3"` ?

If so, just do an `npm install` in that directory.

Now check: does the module in which you'd like to use ReactDOM import `react-dom`?

```
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
// OR
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

If all this is done, your next step might be to check your webpack build script.

Not much else to say without knowing how you've set up the project.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check your entry file (which should be defined inside your webpack.config.js).
Did your forget to put `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom`?

Answer (score 0):

check your version of nodejs, if it is in

version 10 use
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

if it is in version 8 use 
const ReactDOM = require ('react-dom');